# Prove that if $\theta$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $H$, $B \triangleleft H$, and $A=\{g \in G: \theta (g) \in B\}$, then $A \triangleleft G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Prove that if $\theta$ is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $H$, $B \triangleleft H$, and $A=\{g \in G: \theta (g) \in B\}$, then $A \triangleleft G$

So $ \theta :G \to H$ is a homomorphism.
If $B \triangleleft H$, then $A= \{g \in G : \theta(g) \in B\} \triangleleft G$
So $H \triangleleft G,$ for every $a \in G, Ha=aH$ $\iff$ for every $a \in G, h \in H, aha^{-1} \in H$

So this is what I know but I don't know what to do with it next

Answer (score 2):

Let $a \in A$ and $g \in G$ then we have to check $ga g^{-1} \in A$. Using the definition we see $\theta(g a g^{-1}) = \theta(g)\theta(a) \theta(g)^{-1} \in B$ by normality of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

I think here it's easier to work with the element-wise definition of a normal subgroup:
$$
A \lhd G :\Leftrightarrow \forall a\in A, g\in G\colon gag^{-1}\in A.
$$

So let $a\in A$ and $g\in G$.  To verify that $gag^{-1}\in A$, by definition of $A$, we need to show that $\theta(gag^{-1})\in B$.

- Because $\theta$ is a homomorphism, we have $\theta(gag^{-1})=\theta(g)\theta(a){\theta(g)}^{-1}$
- Because $\theta(a)\in B$ (by definition of $A$), $\theta(g)\in H$ and $B\lhd H$, we have that $\theta(g)\theta(a){\theta(g)}^{-1}\in B$ as well
- Hence, $gag^{-1}\in A$

And we're done.

Comment: I think in the last bullet point you meant $gag^{-1} \in A$, isn't it?

Comment: That is correct.